# Multiple RAID arrays on HP Smart Array E200i controller

Tags: raid, hp-smart-array

We currently have a HP ML350 G5 server with 3 disks in a RAID-5 array. Is it possible to add more disks, and have them setup in a seperate RAID array on the E200i controller. I.e. not just adding disks to the current array, but adding a whole new array running at the same time as the current one.

(I'm not really a server guy - hence the noob question :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; this should be possible via the ACU (Array Configuration Utility) from your OS - This means no downtime if your HDs and Cage are HotPlug (Look for reddish/pink parts in HP Servers - They are allways HotPlugable) or via the OptionROM at boottime. The Restrictions regarding RAID Levels apply the same as with your original Disks. Raid 0+1 only without optional Cachememory (which you seem to have installed).