# How to set two RAID1 on the HP SA-E200i controller?

Tags: raid, storage, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have an HP ML350 G5 with a RAID 1 between two SAS disks.

I want to add 2 extra disks and configure a new RAID 1 separated from the other one.

Reading this topic [Multiple RAID arrays on E200i](https://serverfault.com/questions/171296/multiple-raid-arrays-on-hp-smart-array-e200i-controller) it seems possible but how can I perform this operation?

Is it mandatory to have a full system backup before to build the new RAID 1?

Thanks.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Does this need to be done live, or can you have a few minutes of downtime?

Comment: Windows SBS 2008.
Live is better but I can plan a few minutes of downtime if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

- yes, this is possible.
- no, you do not need a backup first.

If you do this, I insist that you upgrade the firmware of the server and RAID controller and disks first. This can all be done via the HP Service Pack for ProLiant DVD.

The simplest approach for what you're asking for is to:

- insert the disks.
- reboot the server.
- press F8 during POST when the Smart Array BIOS configuration screen (RBSU) comes up.
- once in the RBSU, choose "Create New Array".
- select the unassigned new disks.
- choose a RAID level (RAID1).
- follow the prompts to save your changes.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
Can I use also the "Array configuration utility for Windows" or is a better choise to use the RBSU?
Moreover I can't find some distributor that has compatible disks available.
I would like to use disks from WD or Hitachi (enterprise with URE 10^15). Is a good choice?

Comment: You didn't specify the operating system in use, so I provided generic instructions. The Array Configuration Utility works fine as well. It's all self-explanatory. For the disks, can you provide the "Spare Part" number on the capacity label on the front of the disks?

Comment: The part number of the HP disks are 458928-B21 or better 458928-B21.
The WD I'm thinking to buy is a WD RE4 WD1003FBYZ.

Comment: I recommend HP disks. For the era of server you speak of, you can buy off of eBay, as those drives are no longer made. Otherwise, you will need HP carriers. At this point you can install whatever disks you want. There aren't any restrictions. But PLEASE update your system firmware before doing any of this!